# Integrity CI Server not running builds when using Passenger / Apache webserver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, continuous-integration, sinatra

The Integrity App is working fine for me in my OSX dev environment. I've deployed an instance to a Ubuntu server for my production setup, and I'm able to setup a new project. Once I call a manual build to attempt to test a first build the build record is created, but the build is never run.

I've added a bunch of logging to my application and have been able to track the point of failure to when the build job is added in ThreadPool#add It appears everything is running fine to get the job added to the build pool, but that the pool isn't actually running anything despite being spawned and no exceptions being raised.

The environment I'm running is Ubuntu 11.04, RVM & Ruby 1.9.2-p290, Passenger / Apache, and running Integrity from master w/Sqlite3 and ThreadedBuilder.

UPDATE:

I found an article indicating this may be an issue with using Apache & Passenger not loading the Ruby environment properly. This appears to be the case since in dev I'm just running `bundle exec rackup`, and in production I was trying to use Passenger.  So on the production machine I started an instance of Integrity using `bundle exec rackup`, which does indeed actually start running the builds except that it didn't properly find the `bundler` gem as it should have.  I'm sure I can track down a fix for that somehow.

So essentially the issue I am having is with running Integrity with Passenger rather than using rackup.  The article that pointed me in this direction didn't work with their solution of getting Ruby in the Apache environment though.  Can anyone help me determine how to properly run Integrity with Passenger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the way Passenger handles threading.  By changing to the DelayedBuilder using  DelayedJob for builds rather than the ThreadedBuilder I was able to use Passenger as the web server.